# Nativescript Licence documentation

Tags: licensing, apache-2.0

If I use NativeScript in my project, what licence agreement and documentation should I use and include?

The question is, I'm using an open source tool to create mobile apps. Should I include the Apache licence? This was always confusing to me. It's not very clear that I have to include C# licence related documentation if I use it in my projects.

Comment: Can you elaborate? provide links? details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [NativeScript FAQ page](https://www.nativescript.org/faq#how-is-nativescript-licensed?) (which was in the first Google search result) :

> The core of [NativeScript is licensed under the Apache 2.0 software license](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). Basically, you can do what you like with the software, [as long as you include the required notices](https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0)). This permissive license contains a patent license from the contributors of the code and is very business friendly.

I am not a lawyer, but I think you should include:

1. Any copyright information from the creators of NativeScript (Examples: "Copyright 2017 Ty Coon", "Copyright 2005 Mo Nopoly")
2. The full text of the Apache 2.0 license (https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)
3. List any modifications you made in the files. Adding a comment header to every file that you modify might be appropriate.
4. A NOTICE file with any additional attributions (Example: https://www.apache.org/licenses/example-NOTICE.txt)